# Обновлять свойство Button при изменении Text у TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

В окне кнопка, у которой свойство `IsEnabled` должно быть `true` только если `Text` в `TextBox` соответствует паттерну `Regex`. А в других случаях `false`. 
Так же нужно соблюдать паттерн **MVVM**

### View.xaml

```
<Button
    Content="CLICK!"
    Height="45"
    IsEnabled="{Binding NameIsValid, Mode=OneWay}"
    Width="127" />

<TextBox
    Height="32"
    Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    FontSize="20"
    Width="120"/>
```

### ViewModel.cs

```
public bool NameIsValid
{
    get {
        return new Regex(@"^([A-Z]|[А-Я]|І|Ї)([a-z]|[а-я]|і|ї)+").IsMatch(Name);
    }
}
public string Name
{
    get => user.Name;
    set {
        user.Name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        OnPropertyChanged("NameIsValid");
    }
}
```

При вводе валидного значение в `TextBox` свойство `IsEnabled` у кнопки не обновляется, а остается таким какое было при запуске.

Как правильно обновлять свойство элемента при изменении другого в моем случае?

### P.S.

Обнаружил, что обновление случается, только когда TextBox выходит из фокуса. А можно ли что бы сразу при наборе текста были видны обновления?

Comment: ну а сам геттер вызывается?

Comment: @tym32167 а разве OneWayToSource это не делает?

Comment: я про геттер этого свойства `NameIsValid`, он вызывается после этого `OnPropertyChanged("NameIsValid");`?

Comment: @tym32167 немного вас не понимаю. OnPropertyChanged("NameIsValid") сделал в свойстве Name потому что хочу обновлять состояние кнопки при изменении текста. Сделал что бы обновить всех подписчиков. Разве  это не так работает?

Comment: запустите свое приложение, поставьте брейкпоинт вот на этой строчке `return new Regex(@"^([A-Z]|[А-Я]|І|Ї)([a-z]|[а-я]|і|ї)+").IsMatch(Name);` , поменяйте текст в текстбоксе и скажите, брейкпоинт отработал или нет?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, не отработал.

Comment: @tym32167 коечто заметил, обновил вопрос

Comment: то есть таки обновляет. То, что вам надо, тоже легко делается, у меня где то было, сейчас поищу в моих исходниках

Comment: попробуйте вот так `<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`

Comment: @tym32167 да оно! В ответ, уважаемый. Спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что привязка обновлялась при потере фокуса, что является поведением по умолчанию для текстбокса. Вам же нужно вот это

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Обновление привязки при изменении свойства Text текстбокса.